# Hydrogen bonding in solid bicarbonates

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, hydrogen-bond

Why is there two different kinds of hydrogen bonding in solid bicarbonates $\ce{NaHCO3}$ and $\ce{KHCO3}$? In both cases we consider anions of each for hydrogen bonding .

[image]

The anions involved in hydrogen bonding are the same for $\ce{NaHCO3}$ and $\ce{KHCO3}$. But, why is there a difference in hydrogen bonding?

Comment: I think, this can only be answered by looking at the crystal structures, and then by saying ‘because this is what the crystal structure looks like.’

Answer (score 3):

I found something interesting in [*Acta Crystallogr.* **1952,** *5* (2), 292–292](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0365110X52000848), which is attached below.

> [image]

As someone rightly pointed out in the comments, we'll know this only if we know the crystal structure of the compound in question.

What's interesting to note is that hydrogen bonding, and the arrangement of atoms in space under influence of the same varies from compound to compound, and is dependent on the crystal structure of the same.